# R loop to extract CSV files from FTP

Tags: r, loops, ftp

I'm trying to loop through all the CSV files on an FTP site and upload the contents of CSVs with a certain filename to a database.
So far I've been able to

- access the FTP using...

  `getURL((url, userpwd = userpwd, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)`,
- get a list of the filenames using...

  `unlist(strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")`,
- and create a dataframe with a list of the full urls (e.g ftp://sample@ftpserver.name.com/samplename.csv) using...

  ```
  for (i in seq_along(myfiles)) {
    url_list[i,] <- paste(url, myfiles[i],  sep = '')
     }
  ```

How do I loop through this dataframe, filtering for certain filenames, in order to create a new dataframe with all of data from the relevant CSVs? (half the files are named Type1SampleName and half are Type2SampleName)

I would then uploading this data to the database.

Thanks!

Comment: What changes in filenames? The number? By the way, you do not need a loop or data frame: `urls <- paste0(url, myfiles)`.

Comment: I actually figured out how to filter the filenames using grepl `myfiles <- myfiles[grepl("Type1", myfiles)]`
Your suggestion worked a charm - much simpler than a loop. Am I correct in saying this creates a vector which contains all the URLs?
I've tried loading the data from these CSV URLs using: `mydata <- lapply(urls, getURL, userpwd = userpwd, connecttimeout = 60)`
This creates a list with all the raw, unformatted data from each CSV. I'm now trying to figure out how to load this data into a dataframe. Data looks like: \r\n\",\"7.775\",\"7.875\",\"-0.025\"\r\n"
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas? It's almost there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update on how I finished this off and what worked for me in the end...

```
mydata <- lapply(urls, getURL, userpwd = userpwd, connecttimeout = 60)
```

Following on from above..

```
while (i <= length(mydata)) {

mydata1 <- paste0(mydata[[i]])

bin <- read.csv(text = mydata1, header = FALSE, skip = 1)

#Column renaming and formatting here
#Uploading to database using RODBC here
}
```

Thanks for the pointers @Parfait - really appreciated.
Like most problems it looks straightforward after you've done it!

Answer (score 0):

Since [`RCurl::getURL`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.98-1.1/topics/getURL) returns direct HTTP response here being content of CSVs, consider extending your `lapply` function call to pass result into `read.csv` using *text* argument:

```
# VECTOR OF URLs
urls <- paste0(url, myfiles[grep("Type1", myfiles])

# LIST OF DATA FRAMES FROM EACH CSV
mydata <- lapply(urls, function(url) {
     resp <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd, connecttimeout = 60)
     read.csv(text = resp)
})
```

Alternatively, `getURL` supports a callback function with *write* argument:

> Alternatively, if a value is supplied for the `write` parameter, this is returned. This allows the caller to create a handler within the call and get it back. This avoids having to explicitly create and assign it and then call `getURL` and then access the result. Instead, the 3 steps can be inlined in a single call.

```
# USER DEFINED METHOD
import_csv <- function(resp) read.csv(text = resp)

# LONG FORM NOTATION
mydata <- lapply(urls, function(url)
      getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd, connecttimeout = 60, write = import_csv)
)

# SHORT FORM NOTATION
mydata <- lapply(urls, getURL, userpwd = userpwd, connecttimeout = 60, write = import_csv)
```